# How do I get my test SalesForce instance to work with our Java hosting environment?

Tags: security, java, ssl, tls

We are trying to get our J2EE hosting environment (Jboss 7.1.3.AS) working with our test SalesForce instance.  We are running Java 6 v 111

```
java version "1.6.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_111-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.111-b01, mixed mode)
```

Note that this version supports TLS v1.1 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6).  I have added this param on startup

```
 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

However, when we start up our server with our Java SalesForce client, we get the following exception …

```
Caused by: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/28390000001928X
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:121) [force-wsc-uber-33.0.2.jar:]
        at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection.login(EnterpriseConnection.java:1095) [enterprise-1.2.jar:]
        at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection.<init>(EnterpriseConnection.java:385) [enterprise-1.2.jar:]
        at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.Connector.newConnection(Connector.java:27) [enterprise-1.2.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        ... 75 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Only SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 supported
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:188) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1863) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1824) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1807) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1329) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1306) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:476) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1033) [rt.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectRaw(JdkHttpTransport.java:136) [force-wsc-uber-33.0.2.jar:]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectLocal(JdkHttpTransport.java:100) [force-wsc-uber-33.0.2.jar:]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectLocal(JdkHttpTransport.java:95) [force-wsc-uber-33.0.2.jar:]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connect(JdkHttpTransport.java:91) [force-wsc-uber-33.0.2.jar:]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:95) [force-wsc-uber-33.0.2.jar:]
        ... 83 more
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Only SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 supported
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.calculateMasterSecret(Handshaker.java:995) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.calculateKeys(Handshaker.java:948) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:957) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:287) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:817) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:753) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:989) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1295) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1322) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
        ... 93 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Only SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 supported
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.TlsMasterSecretGenerator.engineInit(TlsMasterSecretGenerator.java:53)
        at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.init(KeyGenerator.java:406) [jce.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.init(KeyGenerator.java:382) [jce.jar:1.6.0_111]
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.calculateMasterSecret(Handshaker.java:984) [jsse.jar:1.6.0_111]
```

What version of TLS is SalesForce expecting, and how should we configure our Java environment to use it?  Note that it is sadly not an option to upgrade past Java 6 at this time. - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce is expecting TLS 1.1 or 1.2.

I'm pretty sure that your specific Java build only supports TLS 1.1 (but maybe I missed the relevant info in your link). It looks like 1.2 support is in 1.6.0_115-b32.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-156328.html#R160_111

Comment: Good call.  Chagning the param to "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1" worked.